# Proof that $Aut(P) \cong H^2(X;\mathbb Z)$, where $P \to X$ is a principal $PU(\mathcal H)$-bundle.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, automorphism-group, principal-bundles

In Atiyah and Segal's [Twisted K-Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0407054), they twice state the isomorphism $Aut(P) \cong H^2(X;\mathbb Z)$, where $P \to X$ is a principal $PU(\mathcal H)$-bundle.

I'm trying to prove this myself.
It's clear when $P$ is the trivial bundle: automorphisms of the trivial bundle correspond with maps $X \to PU(\mathcal H) \simeq K(\mathbb Z,2)$.

For general $P$, the best I have is $Aut(P) \cong Map(P, PU(\mathcal H))^{PU(\mathcal H)}$, where the right side of this equation denotes $PU(\mathcal H)$-equivariant maps with $PU(\mathcal H)$ acting on itself via conjugation.
This doesn't seem isomorphic to $Map(X, PU(\mathcal H))$.

One strategy might be to show that $Aut(P)$ is isomorphic to the group of self-homotopies of the classifying map $X \to BPU(\mathcal H)$.
From here, I'm still not sure how to get from these self homotopies to maps $X \to PU(\mathcal H)$.

Can someone help me get there? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's Proposition 2.2 in the cited paper. Have you considered following the outlined proof? Which part(s) are you struggling with?

Comment: Silly me; I thought I was quite familiar with the paper but somehow missed that it was one of their results. I've managed to fill in their proof, thanks for pointing it out to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ben pointed out in a comment, Atiyah and Segal actually have this result in the paper as Proposition 2.2.
Their proof is quite terse, so I thought I would at least fill in the details here. The quotes I give in the proof come from the linked paper.

I'll write $U := U(\mathcal H)$ and $PU := PU(\mathcal H)$.

**Theorem:**
Let $P \to X$ be a principal $PU$-bundle.
The connected components of the group of automorphisms of $P$ are in bijection with $H^2(X;\mathbb Z)$.

**Proof:**

> An automorphism of P is a section of a bundle on X whose fibre is
> PU(H).

Let $\operatorname{Ad}(P) := P \times_{PU} PU$ be the bundle with fiber $PU$ coming from the action of $PU$ on itself via conjugation.
That is, $\operatorname{Ad}(P)$ is the quotient of $P \times PU$ under the relation $(p \cdot u, A) \sim (p, uAu^{-1})$, where $u \in PU$.
This is the bundle they refer to: automorphisms of $P$ are in bijection with sections of $\operatorname{Ad}(P)$.

> This bundle, however, comes from one with fibre U(H), and so it
> is trivial.

Automorphisms of $U$ induce automorphisms of $PU$ by passing to the quotient.
Hence, a bundle with fiber $U$ induces a bundle with fiber $PU$.
One way to think about it is that you turn the $\operatorname{Aut}(U)$-valued transition functions into $\operatorname{Aut}(PU)$-valued transition functions by composing with $\operatorname{Aut}(U) \to \operatorname{Aut}(PU)$.

$\operatorname{Ad}(P)$ is induced from $P$ via the map $PU \to \operatorname{Aut}(PU)$ that sends an element to its corresponding inner automorphism.
This map factors through $PU \to \operatorname{Aut}(U)$, since $PU$ also acts on $U$ via conjugation.
This means that $\operatorname{Ad}(P)$ is induced by a bundle with fibers $U$; specifically, the bundle is $P \times_{PU} U$, where $PU$ acts on $U$ by inner automorphisms.

$U$ is contractible, and so any bundle with fiber $U$ is necessarily trivial.
Thus $\operatorname{Ad}(P)$ is induced from a trivial bundle and is itself trivial.

> The group of automorphisms can therefore be identified with the maps from X to PU(H), which is an Eilenberg-Maclane space K(Z, 2).

$\operatorname{Ad}(P)$ is a trivial $PU$-bundle, and so its sections can be identified with maps $X \to PU$.

To summarise and conclude:
$$
    \pi_0(\operatorname{Aut}(P)) 
    \cong \pi_0\Gamma(X, \operatorname{Ad}(P)) 
    \cong \pi_0 \Gamma(X, X \times PU)
    \cong [X, PU]
    \cong [X, K(\mathbb Z,2)]
    \cong H^2(X;\mathbb Z).
$$